# PHP and MYSQL Database Retrieving

Tags: php

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "admin";
    $dbname = "register";

    // Create connection 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<br> email: " . $row["email"] . "<br>";
         }
    }
```

I am trying to get only the last row and the email column. The method that I am doing takes every row, with the email column. If somebody could adjust my code and comment it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why not limit 1 and order by primary key as DESC?

Comment: Can u put example code? I dont understajd

Comment: What do I echo if I use primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to

- To get the LAST row sort the results descending on a fields that gets incremented with every new row like the auto increment field [I am assuming that id] ( ORDER BY id DESC)
- limit the rows returned to 1 ( LIMIT 1 )

So try this query instead

```
SELECT email FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

In your code

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<br> email: " . $row["email"] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: What do i output then? do I do a simple echo? What do i echo?

Comment: @user3211414: The code you posted is *already* outputting the value.  In what way is that not working?

Comment: See the query placed in your code and amended accordingly for one result row being returned. It should not have actually been necessary to change it, but it is more precise this way and self documentary

Comment: Thank You! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & Simple:

```
$sql = 'SELECT U.email FROM users AS U ORDER BY U.id DESC LIMIT 1';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object();
echo 'Email ID>> '.$row->email;
```

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. How does your code solve the problem and how is the solution different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Above query will sort rows in descending order of **id** and by using LIMIT 1 clause it will retrieve only single record (i.e. email) here. 

We get the record by fetch_object as required.